# Flex Wrap + TransformY not working in Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, safari, flexbox, transform

So I'm using Flex-Wrap to keep a lot of my Bootstrap 3 columns at the same height as one another. However, when I want to centre that content within it's own column vertically & horizontally, I use this typical code:

```
.equal {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.centered {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

While this works TOTALLY fine in Opera, Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer/Edge. It is **Safari** that refuses to play ball and **messes up the transformY segment of the transform code.**

I have attached a ***[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/CharlieMcShane/pen/mXzpEr?editors=1100)*** for you to see exactly how it is messing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr; [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/danbrazier/pen/aqRYLK?editors=1100)

There are a few things here that I'd think about.

Firstly, flexbox and positioning have a few quirks when used closely together - particularly with Safari. Most of the issues here are ironed out, but there are still a few small, frustrating things I come across from time-to-time.

Secondly, it looks like you're using some of your own code to duplicate things that already exist in Bootstrap, which is probably confusing the issue.

I've structured my example code, and have vaguely used flex classes that you'll find in Bootstrap 4, that way you can ease the burden if and when you migrate over.

The general concept here, from my point of view:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row d-flex">
    <!-- Make the row a flex wrapper, this will make columns the same height -->

        <div class="col d-flex">
        <!-- Make each col a flex wrapper, to use flex properties to dynamically center content -->
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex">
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great points, if I'm to use flex or equal columns, I need to follow suite and have the content within those equal columns be centered with flex also. Thanks a ton for the great advice, the Codepen example works as intended also!